# Integration Question - Not sure how to approach

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I have absolutely no idea how to approach this question:

$$\int \frac{x^2}{(15+6x-9x^2)^{3/2}} \ \mathrm{d}x$$

I'm almost positive that it has something to do with trigonometric substitution, but no matter how much I rearrange the equation or try to perform substitution I'm just not seeing how to solve it.

Comment: Complete the square, we get $16-(3x-1)^2$. Let $3x-1=4\sin \theta$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas From there, I get 3dx = 4cosѲ, so I substitute in and get:

$$\int \frac{(\frac{4sinѲ+1}{3})^2* \frac{4cosѲ}{3}dѲ}{(4cosѲ^2)^{3/2}} \ \mathrm{d}x$$

(4cosѲ^2)^(3/2) = 8cosѲ^3

I've solved the equation wrong, and I'm positive I've done something wrong in this step.

Comment: I won't worry about constants. We end up with something like $\frac{(a\sin x +b)^2}{\cos^2 x}$. Expand the top. We need to integrate $\frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x}$, so $\tan^2 x$. This is $\sec^2 x-1$, has integral $\tan x-x$. We also need to integrate $\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2 x}$, that is, $\tan x\sec x$, which has integral $\sec x$. And we need to integrate $\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}$, which is $\sec^2 x$, easy to integrate.

Comment: Oh, alright. I DID integrate it right then, but I don't know what to replace theta with in my final answer, as it should be expressed in terms of x. Right now I have:  
8/9 tanѲ - 8/9 Ѳ + 4/9 secѲ + 1/18 tanѲ + C  I thought that because 3x-1 = 4sinѲ, Ѳ = arcsin((3x-1)/4)

Comment: Yes, that's correct. For the trig functions of $\theta$ that occur in your answer, draw a right triangle. Label one of the angles (not the right angle!) $\theta$. Label the hypotenuse $4$, and label the side opposite to $\theta$ by $3x-1$. Then you can use the triangle to read off what the various trig function are in terms of $x$.

Comment: Oh, right! I forgot about that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AndréNicolas Same request here, Please!

Comment: @@Integrator: I have written out the requested answer. Without the interaction with OP it loses interest. I think for the other problem you mentioned, the comments are even less worth turning into an answer. They were useful to OP at the time, but that's all. If you disagree please feel free to answer.

Answer (score 1):

To prepare for the trigonometric substitution, we complete the square, noting that $15+6x-9x^2=16-(3x-1)^2$.  Let $3x-1=4\sin\theta$. Then $3\,dx=4\cos\theta\,d\theta$, and our integral can be rewritten as
$$\int \frac{(1+4\sin \theta)^2}{9}\frac{1}{8\cos^3 \theta}\frac{4}{3}\cos\theta\,d\theta.$$

Our integral then simplifies to
$$\frac{1}{54}\int\left(\sec^2\theta+8\sec\theta\tan\theta+16\tan^2\theta      \right)\,d\theta.$$
Now we are essentially finished, for $\int\sec^2\theta\,d\theta=\tan\theta+C$, while $\int \sec\theta\tan\theta=\sec\theta+C$. Finally, to integrate $\tan^2\theta$ rewrite as $\sec^2\theta-1$.

To express the integral in terms of $x$, draw as usual a right triangle with hypotenuse $4$ and leg $3x-1$ opposite $\angle\theta$. Then we csn use the Pythagorean Theorem to write down the length of the other leg, and read off the trigonometric  functions of $\theta$ from the picture.